# How to upload image in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

In view

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('welcome/do_upload');?>
 <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
```

In controler

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        echo 'error';
    } else {

        return array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }
}
```

And I call this function like this

```
 $this->data['data'] = $this->do_upload();
```

and view this image:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($data['upload_data'] as $item => $value):?>
<li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I don't know what's the error.

Comment: Write `<?php var_dump($data['upload_data']); ?>` in your view and check the result. as a side-note: do NOT echo `'error'` in controller when uploading fails.

Comment: It gives me null. I want to ask one question where upload folder put?

Comment: When you set `./uploads/` as upload folder, it should located at the root of your CodeIgniter installation (near of `index.php`).

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in your controller, please post further info.

Comment: I put this folder near index.php but still it gives me null output.

Comment: For file uploading my code is as mentioned in it only no further code for file uploading, i am working on student management system application.

Comment: I mean where you've used `$this->data['data'] = $this->do_upload();`, not the entire controller, how do you send `$this->data` to the view?

Comment: instead of echo "error" write $this->upload->display_errors();die; to view the actual error returned and <?php var_dump($data['upload_data']); ?> to view the result

Comment: No error is displayed blank page is open...:(

Comment: @HashemQolami Is there any option uploading both data and file in one form?

Comment: @darshan Of course! just add enough `<input>` tags as you want, after `form_open_multipart();`. the values will be sent by `POST` method which you can obtain by `$this->input->post('field_name');`.

Comment: I guess the problem is you send the form request to `welcome/do_upload` and call the `do_upload` method in another method, so the `$_FILES` would be empty on the second method. Try to send form request to the second method, where you called `$this->do_upload();` in it, like: `form_open_multipart('welcome/SECOND_METHOD');`

Comment: @darshan I'll post it as an answer then, kindly mark it as having solved your problem.

Comment: <p><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /></p> i used this tag and when i call var_dump( $_POST, $_GET, $_FILES ); image is get in the $_POST method i want to upload that file is there any suggestion??

Comment: if you want to read a tutorial explaining codeigniter file upload in detail, you can find here . https://programmerblog.net/codeigniter-file-upload-example/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems the problem is you send the form request to `welcome/do_upload`, and call the `Welcome::do_upload()` method in another one by `$this->do_upload()`.

Hence when you call the `$this->do_upload();` within your **second method**, the `$_FILES` array would be **empty**.

And that's why `var_dump($data['upload_data']);` returns `NULL`.

If you want to upload the file from `welcome/second_method`, send the form request to the **welcome/second_method** where you call `$this->do_upload();`.

Then change the form helper function (within the *View*) as follows<sup>1</sup>:

```
// Change the 'second_method' to your method name
echo form_open_multipart('welcome/second_method');
```

---

### File Uploading with CodeIgniter

CodeIgniter **[has documented the Uploading process](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)** very well, by using the File Uploading library.

You could take a look at the sample code in the user guide; And also, in order to get a better understanding of the *uploading configs*, Check the *Config items Explanation* section at the end of the manual page.

Also there are couple of articles/samples about the file uploading in CodeIgniter, you might want to consider:

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684
- http://runnable.com/UhIc93EfFJEMAADX/how-to-upload-file-in-codeigniter
- http://jamshidhashimi.com/image-upload-with-codeigniter-2/
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684
- http://hashem.ir/CodeIgniter/libraries/file_uploading.html *(CodeIgniter 3.0-dev User Guide)*

Just as a **side-note:** Make sure that you've loaded the `url` and `form` helper functions before using the CodeIgniter sample code:

```
// Load the helper files within the Controller
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->helper('url');

// Load the helper files within the application/config/autoload
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');
```

---

---

<sub>1. The form must be "multipart" type for file uploading. Hence you should use `form_open_multipart()` helper function which returns:  
``</sub>

Comment: I stumbled on this Q&A from a Google search for another question. You may want to update your answer with the following link http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload%20files as the http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html library is out of date.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you Fred. The answer is almost 3 yrs old :) and I hadn't had the chance to come back to it. Will update the answer with v3 ASAIC.

Comment: i have found this tutorial regarding this
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/codeigniter-upload-file-image/

Comment: uploading file in the same time sending the post variable would it be possible?

Answer (score 11):

**Simple Image upload in codeigniter**

Find below code for easy image upload:

```
public function doupload()
     {
        $upload_path="https://localhost/project/profile"  
        $uid='10'; //creare seperate folder for each user 
        $upPath=upload_path."/".$uid;
        if(!file_exists($upPath)) 
        {
                   mkdir($upPath, 0777, true);
        }
        $config = array(
        'upload_path' => $upPath,
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000", 
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024"
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userpic'))
        { 
            $data['imageError'] =  $this->upload->display_errors();
             
        }
        else
        {
            $imageDetailArray = $this->upload->data();
            $image =  $imageDetailArray['file_name'];
        }
        
     }
```

Comment: how about the data form submitted when we do uploading image, is it possible @Hiren?

Comment: yes it's possible, you can pass data along with image

Answer (score 3):

```
//this is the code you have to use in you controller 

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';  

// directory (http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/your directory)

        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';  
//Image type  

        $config['max_size'] = 0;    

 // I have chosen max size no limit 
        $new_name = time() . '-' . $_FILES["txt_file"]['name']; 

//Added time function in image name for no duplicate image 

        $config['file_name'] = $new_name;

//Stored the new name into $config['file_name']

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload() && !empty($_FILES['txt_file']['name'])) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('production/create_images', $error);
        } else {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();   
        }
```

Comment: How do you pass `$error` ti the view without getting any errors?

Comment: is it possible posting the data as well while uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this. It works perfectly:

```
public function uploadImageFile() //gallery insert
{ 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $new_image_name = time() . str_replace(str_split(' ()\\/,:*?"<>|'), '', 
    $_FILES['image_file']['name']);
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/gallery/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = $new_image_name;
    $config['max_size']  = '0';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';
    $config['$min_width'] = '0';
    $config['min_height'] = '0';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image_file');
    $title=$this->input->post('title');
    $value=array('title'=>$title,'image_name'=>
    $new_image_name,'crop_name'=>$crop_image_name);}
```

Comment: is this call executed from a multipart-form POST entry?
i just wondering the form submitted whole data along with the image succesfully....

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_folder = APPPATH . "../images/owner_profile/" . $_POST ['mob_no'] [0] . $na;
            if (isset ( $_FILES ['image'] ) && $_FILES ['image'] ['error'] == 0) {
                list ( $a, $b ) = explode ( '.', $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] );
                $b = end ( explode ( '.', $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] ) );
                $up = move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'], $image_folder . "." . $b );
                $path = ($_POST ['mob_no'] [0] . $na . "." . $b);
```

Comment: See... First create <form>  then add multipart tag for that form, means you can upload images to it. then put the name of that image tag i.e. "image"

Comment: then in codeigniter controller , write the above code

Comment: so your image will save in perticular folder and only the name of that image will store in the database tables

Answer (score 0):

Below code for an uploading a single file at a time.
This is correct and perfect to upload a single file.
Read all commented instructions and follow the code.
Definitely, it is worked.

```
public function upload_file() {
    ***// Upload folder location***
    $config['upload_path'] = './public/upload/';

    ***// Allowed file type***
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';

    ***// Max size, i will set 2MB***
    $config['max_size'] = '2024';

    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    ***// load upload library***            
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    ***// do_upload is the method, to send the particular image and file on that 
       // particular 
       // location that is detail in $config['upload_path']. 
       // In bracks will set name upload, here you need to set input name attribute 
       // value.***

    if($this->upload->do_upload('upload')) {
       $data = $this->upload->data();
       $post['upload'] = $data['file_name'];
    } else {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

check $this->upload->initialize($config); this works fine for me

```
    $new_image_name = "imgName".time() . str_replace(str_split(' ()\\/,:*?"<>|'), '', 
    $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = $new_image_name;
    $config['max_size']  = '0';
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|mp4|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = url_title("imgsclogo");
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE; 
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $data = $this->upload->data();
}
```