# Image is not uploaded into database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying ti upload image in the form. All the data in form can be stored into the database accept the images. And the images is not insert into the upload_path also. I wan to make like when user fill in all the form information and upload an image, user click the submit button and all the data including image store into database. What wrong with my code? thank you.

//view.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('writereview/create');?>
<label for="sitename"><span>Sitename <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="sitename" value="" /></label>
<input type="file" name="images"  size="20" /> <br />
<label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
```

//controller

```
public function create() //insert data
{
    $data['title'] = 'Write Review'; // Capitalize the first letter 
    $this->load->helper(array('html', 'url', 'form'));

    $this->config_model->writereview();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('writereview/writereview');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

//model

```
public function writereview()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $type = explode('.', $_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
    $type = strtolower($type[count($type)-1]);
    $url = "./assets/images/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
    if(in_array($type, array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png")))
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]))
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"],$url))
                return $url;


    $data = array(
        'sitename' => $this->input->post('sitename'),
        'images'=>$this->input->post('images')
    );
    return $this->db->insert('review', $data);
}
```

Comment: file name is `name="images"` and you `$_FILES["pic"]` that's wrong . Use `$_FILES["images"]`

Comment: I am sorry. It not working too..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload image in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315962/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter)

Comment: for single upload images it work fine. But when add in other form data. It only manage to store the form data but not the image.

Answer (score 0):

change your insert data array

```
$data = array(
        'sitename' => $this->input->post('sitename'),
        'images'=>$uploaded_file_name
    );
```

also change `$_FILES["pic"]["name"] to $_FILES["images"]["name"]`

there is no post key named **images** as the input type is file ...

Here is the complete code for your example...

```
        $image_name ='';
        if (isset($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] != '') 
        {
          $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/';
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
          $config['max_size'] = '20000'; // change it to your max file size
          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
          $this->upload->initialize($config);
          if (!$this->upload->do_upload('images')) {//if upload error
            print_r($this->upload->display_errors());//print error
          }else{
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $image_name = $data['file_name'];
          }
        }
        $data = array(
           'sitename' => $this->input->post('sitename'),
           'images'=>$image_name
        );
        return $this->db->insert('review', $data);
```

Comment: I changed but when i click submit button, nothing happen. It wont link to writereview/create.

Comment: I just know I don have any library file call upload. So what should include in upload library?

Comment: its in the code... $this->load->library('upload', $config);

Comment: Mean I do not need any library file call upload? I am sorry, because I am a new programmer and new to codeigniter..

Comment: What you mean? This is the Codeigniter way to upload the file and upload library already there in the Codeigniter?

Comment: In my application/library don have the file call upload.php. So how could it load to my library file call upload?

Comment: you can't find it in application/libraries ... upload library is part of codeigniter system itself... look in system/libraries

Comment: Oh.. Now I totally understand. I thought its in application/library... But I still unable to click the submit button. It nothing changed.