# codeigniter $_FILES function

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

In Codeigniter syntax for normal PHP code `$_POST['name']` is `$this->input->post('name')`. Does anyone knows what is syntax in CI for `$_FILES['file']`?

I don't want to upload, I want to catch file and make some action before uploading. In upload helper is only this: `$this->upload->do_upload('file')` - and that is uploading. I want to manage file before this step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: CI has its own File Uploading Class, you should Google that.

Comment: Yes it has, but even google can't help me with answer on this question. I need some experience CI user.

Comment: Here, I did it "for you" http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload%20files

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload image in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315962/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter)

Comment: No you didn't and isn't duplicate. I know how to upload ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')), but I don't want to do that. I want to catch file, same as I can in PHP $_FILES['file'], but I want to do that in CI way.

Answer (score 0):

You can call $_FILES directly before uploading

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);//Load upload library class
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
 //manage the file $key and then upload it
 this->upload->do_upload($key);
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to use $_FILES, I want to use for that CI syntax if exist?

Comment: In the previous comment which you deleted, you said you are going to check. Whether you checked it? is it working or not?

Comment: Yes, but I read answer again and I saw $_FILES, and that is exactly I want to avoid in code. Is it possible to write code in CI without $_FILES and somehow catch file? If is possible then great, otherwise thanks for effort, I will use $_FILES, what to do.

Comment: If you check the Upload.php library file, they also used $_FILES. So there is nothing wrong in using it.

Comment: I saw, and I will use $_FILES. I didn't manage to find another solution. This can't be locked. Thanks