# Array save in database instead of value in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, implode

I have a model function like following. When I click submit, all the data gets saved in the database, but the image field value is stored as  `Array,Array,Array`.

How to solve this issue? I am a beginner with PHP and CodeIgniter.

```
public function create_post($post_image){
    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
    $image = implode(',',$post_image);

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
        'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'post_image' => $image
    );

    return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
}
```

Comment: do you want to save image name?

Comment: @Harun Anwar, comment all codes and just add `print_r($post_image)` and see what is showing... then copy those code and add it here. so we can find solution for you..

Comment: Do some debugging. Find out what the value of `$post_image` is.

Comment: `$post_image` is a `$_FILES` array __obviously__.

Comment: I got following after print_r($post_image);
Array ( [images] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => img.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => D:\xampp\tmp\php7052.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 622030 ) ) )

Comment: [Image upload in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315962/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Image upload in folder but doesn't store a image name in database

Comment: @HarunAnwar
As you can see it's returning 2 dimensional array so when you implode $post_image then it's implode an array. 

If you want to store image name then do something like
$image =$post_image['images']['name'][0];

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
public function create_post($post_image){
                    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
                    $image = implode(',',$post_image);

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'post_image' => $image['images']['name'][0]
        );
        return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
    }
```

But firstly make sure you are getting values in $post_image variable.

Answer (score 0):

replace your function with following codes.

```
public function create_post($post_image){
    extract($this->input->post());
    $slug = url_title($title);
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $post_image = $post_image['images']['name'][0]; 

    $this->db->insert('posts', compact('title','slug','body','category_id','user_id','post_image'));
    return ($this->db->trans_status()) ? $this->db->insert_id() : false;
}
```