# How add image into form with fields code Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to Codeigniter and new to the MVC webdesign, i have plant insert    form i want to upload image and save image name into database i tried many codes but not works please help me to write upload function

plant insert form is below here

```
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('AddPlant/InsertPlant')?>
        <div class="form-group has-error">
            <label for="name">Name <span class="require">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="description" > 
        </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
           <label for="exampleSelect1" class='control-label'>Job Type</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
            <option value="1">Level 1</option>
            <option value="2">Level 2</option>
            <option value="3">Level 3</option>
           </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p><span class="require">*</span> - required fields</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Plant Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="plantimg">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Create
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                Cancel
            </button>
        </div>

    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

My Codeigniter model

```
       <?php
       class Model_plants extends CI_Model
       {

     function insertPlantData(){

    $data =array(

        'name'=> $this->input->post('name',TRUE),
        'description'=> $this->input->post('description',TRUE),
         'age'=> $this->input->post('age',TRUE),

    );
    return $this->db->insert('plants',$data);
}
}
```

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315962/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload image in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315962/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter)

Comment: all codes have upload field only i want upload field with another field

Comment: first change your form type from `form_open()` to `form_open_multipart()`

Comment: '   

        $target_dir = "./upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . time().basename($_FILES["plantimg"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $imgName = time().basename($_FILES["plantimg"]["name"]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["plantimg"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
'

Comment: but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

***Note*** : make sure you have load `database` and `upload` library either in autoload or in controller

First your form should be like this :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('AddPlant/InsertPlant')?>
    ............
 <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Your controller should be like this :

```
public function InsertPlant()
{
    /*here make sure your path is correct*/
    $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH .'assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('plantimg'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);die;
    }
    else
    {
        //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $file_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        /*here assuming that your column name for image is image_name, change it not*/
        $data =array(
                'name'=> $this->input->post('name',TRUE),
                'description'=> $this->input->post('description',TRUE),
                'age'=> $this->input->post('age',TRUE),
                'image_name'=> $file_name,
        );
        return $this->db->insert('plants',$data);
    }
}
```