# how to insert image in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

How to insert image in  database without uploading any folder?

My controller side code is below :

```
$data['f_name'] = $this->input->post('f_name');  
$data['l_name'] = $this->input->post('l_name');  
$data['contact'] = $this->input->post('contact');  
$data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');  
$data['uid'] = $this->input->post('uid');  
//$data['user_image'] = $this->input->post->userfiles['file_name'];
```

My model side code id below :

```
$this->db->where('id',$data['uid']);  
$this->db->update('users',array(  
'first_name' =>     $data['f_name'],  
'last_name' =>    $val['l_name'],  
'email'  =>    $val['email'],  
 'phone'  =>    $data['contact']    
));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How add image into form with fields code Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839475/how-add-image-into-form-with-fields-code-codeigniter)

Comment: but  my problem is without uploading in any folder how to take image data in variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `$_FILES` to get file name

First your form should be like this :

```
<form action="<?=site_url('controller_name/method_name');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

  <input type="file" name="test" id="">

  /*and other input fields*/

  <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
```

In controller get the file name using variable `$_FILES`

```
public function method_name()
{
   // as you mention u don't want to upload the file

   $file_name = $_FILES['test']['name'];
   $data['user_image'] = $file_name; 

   $data['f_name'] = $this->input->post('f_name');  
   $data['l_name'] = $this->input->post('l_name');  
   $data['contact'] = $this->input->post('contact');  
   $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');  
   $data['uid'] = $this->input->post('uid');


}
```

For more :
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: sir, can you also help for how to view image in browser from database like other fields of table i tried image name is display, but how can display image

Comment: for that you have to upload image in one of the folders of your project and to show you have to put the path of image in src attribute of image

Answer (score 1):

An image is always first uploaded to a temporary folder. It's common that afterwards it shall be stored in a folder, it's then moved with the PHP-function `move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination)` to a folder of choice.
You can read [about the common procedures and pitfalls on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

If you want to store the file(s) in the database I suppose you could do it from the temporary directory, but cleaning up that directory you had to do by yourself.
Important to know is the Variable [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) which holds an array including details like temporary-name(s) and upload-name(s).

Be advised that it might be hard to handle the database for moving, duplicating, etc. especially in the case of any error if many files are stored inside. The database can get very fast very large. It's not a fault to store images in the database but it's not common practice and has some negative aspects. At least I'd separate media then from any data in the database by separated tables, so your decision should have some impact in the database-design.