# image file not showing in upload folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have spend days trying to make image file i uploaded shows in its folder but when i upload an image file it goes to database but not displaying in folder i dont know why.

```
 public function additems()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 106660;
                $config['max_width']            = 1026664;
                $config['max_height']           = 76668;



                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->load->view('templates/dashboard_head.php');

                 $this->load->view('admin/create_product');
                 $this->load->view('templates/admin_sidebar');
                 $this->load->view('templates/admin_footer');
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                 if($this->input->post('submit'))
 {
 //get form's data and store in local varable

 $name=$this->input->post('name');
 $price=$this->input->post('price');
$description=$this->input->post('discription');
 $code = $this->input->post('code');
 $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $image =  $_FILES['image']['name']; 
//call saverecords method of Hello_Model and pass variables as parameter
 $this->admin->insert_products($name, $price, $description,$code,$image); 
 echo "<script>
window.alert('added succesfully');
</script>";
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload image in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315962/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter)

Comment: not still showing in folder if i upload the image file

Comment: can you use <?php echo form_open_multipart('controller/method_name');?>

Comment: where is `do_upload()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image gets assigned a temporary name on upload. You have to move it using something like this:

```
$uploadDirectory = './uploads';
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadDirectory );
```