# How to display disallowed file type error message in case of upload in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic **[blog application](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog)** with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

The posts, of course, have main images. There is a *default image* if no image is uploaded by the user but, if an image *is* uploaded, there are *only 3 types allowed*: jpg, jpeg and png.

Wanting to warn the user in case she/he tries to upload other file formats, I did this in the **Posts** controller:

```
// Upload image
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '2048';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){

    $data['uerrors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

    if ($data['uerrors']) {
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        $post_image = 'default.jpg';
    }

} else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
}
```

In the view I have:

```
<?php foreach ($uerrors as $uerror): ?>
  <span><?php echo $uerror; ?></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Yet, I get a *Undefined variable: uerrors* error.

Here is the entire `create()` method:

```
public function create() {

    // Only logged in users can create posts
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $data = $this->get_data();
    $data['tagline'] = "Add New Post";

    if ($data['categories']) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
            $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
        }
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        // Create slug (from title)
        $slug = url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title')), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, null);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }

        // Upload image
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){

            $data['uerrors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            if ($data['uerrors']) {
                $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
                $this->load->view('partials/footer');
            } else {
                $post_image = 'default.jpg';
            }

        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }

        $this->Posts_model->create_post($post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created');
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded to display the upload errors (*if* upload is attempted, otherwise a *default image* is used) by modifying `create()` this way:

```
public function create() {

    // Only logged in users can create posts
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $data = $this->get_data();
    $data['tagline'] = "Add New Post";

    if ($data['categories']) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
            $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
        }
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        // Create slug (from title)
        $slug = url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title')), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, null);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }

        // Upload image
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){

            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            // Display upload validation errors 
            // only if a file is uploaded and there are errors
            if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
                $errors = [];
            }

            if (empty($errors)) {
                $post_image = 'default.jpg';
            } else {
                $data['upload_errors'] = $errors;
            }

        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            $this->Posts_model->create_post($post_image, $slug);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created');
            redirect('/');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
            $this->load->view('partials/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

In the `create-post.php` view I have:

```
<?php if(isset($upload_errors)){
   foreach ($upload_errors as $upload_error) {
    echo $upload_error;
   }
 }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your upload code looks okay, but you need to update these following changes.

1. Pass data to your `'dashboard/create-post'` view as you have passed to your `'partials/header'` view. Your `'dashboard/create-post'` view is not getting any upload error messages, so it is saying `'Undefined variable: uerrors'`. So, your upload code should be like this -

> ```
> if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
>     $data['uerrors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
>     if ($data['uerrors']) {
>         $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
>         $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post', $data);
>         $this->load->view('partials/footer');
>     } else {
>         $post_image = 'default.jpg';
>     }
> } else {
>     $post_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
> }
> ```

2. As [CodeIgniter Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::display_errors) says, 'display_errors()' returns string, not array, you don't have to loop through the error. Just echo it on your `'dashboard/create-post'` view.

For your convenience, make your upload task in different method so that you can re-use this in update method also. As example -

```
private function uploadFile(){
    if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] === '') {
        return array(
            'status' => TRUE,
            'message' => 'No file selected.',
            'file_name' => 'default.jpg'
        );
    }

    // Upload image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        return array(
            'status' => FALSE,
            'message' => $this->upload->display_errors('<p class="text-danger ">', '</p>'),
            'file_name' => ''
        );
    }else{
        return array(
            'status' => TRUE,
            'message' => 'File uploaded successfully',
            'file_name' => $this->upload->data('file_name')
        );
    }
}
```

Then your entire create method should look like this -

```
public function create() {
    // Only logged in users can create posts
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $data = $this->get_data();
    $data['tagline'] = "Add New Post";

    if ($data['categories']) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
            $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
        }
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        $upload = $this->uploadFile();

        if($upload['status'] === FALSE){
            $data['upload_error'] = $upload['message'];

            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post', $data);
            $this->load->view('partials/footer');
        }else{
            // Create slug (from title)
            $slug = url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title')), 'dash', TRUE);
            $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, null);
            if ($slugcount > 0) {
                $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
            }

            $this->Posts_model->create_post($upload['file_name'], $slug);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created');
            redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

And finally add this line of code on your `'dashboard/create-post'` view file, right after file input button.

```
<?php if(isset($upload_error)) echo $upload_error; ?>
```

I think all should work.

Comment: What I need is a way to tell the user that she/he tried to load the wrong **file-type** (a PDF, for instance),  **not** that no file was uploaded. If no file is uploaded, then there is a default image (see `$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';`).

Comment: CodeIgniter does not provide any option to customize upload error messages. Instead, you can do following -
1. Tell the user which file types are supported to upload in create post page.
2. Use the `accept` attribute in your files input. It will only show accepted file types while selecting a file. Check `W3Schools` for the attributes usage.

Also there was a typo on `uploadFile()` method which I have updated. Please replace the code with the updated one.

Answer (score 1):

There  are three things I picked up here

1) not passing $data  to the correct view  as mentioned before

2) expecting array instead of string on the view ie wrong data type

3) lastly function do_upload()  expects parameter string $field. This is missing that's why you are having only the no upload selected error. If this parametre is set codeigniter really throws wrong filetype error. I did this to test

on my view

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/welcome/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="lname" ><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

then in my controller

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload("lname")){
```

Upload a wrong file type to test this error. You may need to go an extra length to   detect the filetype for the actual upload file.

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that a variable doesn't exist or was not initialized. Looking at this code

```
$data['uerrors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

if ($data['uerrors']) {
```

I think that you probably have a `$uerrors` variable somewhere (not shown in this code) which was not initialized. Note that I do not believe that the `array` index `'uerrors'` would cause you trouble in the chunk above, because, first of all you define it and second, if you reference an `array` item which does not exist, then you will get a different error message from the one quoted in the question.

Comment: I know, but I **did** pass it to `$data`, so why the error?

Comment: I posted the entire `create()` method.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir at which line is it crashing? Is it ```if ($data['uerrors']) {```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Whatever, the only condition in which the variable `$uerrors` will set is when `create()` method will execute which I believe would get executed on POST request. Besides, you didn't mention which part of view is this:

```
<?php foreach ($uerrors as $uerror): ?>
  <span><?php echo $uerror; ?> </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If it's `dashboard/create-post` view then try passing `$data` directly to this view instead of passing it to `partials/header`

**Note:** I just checked the codeigniter [View/Controller samples](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/#loadview) and I found it to be a good practice to check variable using `isset()` function call, so instead of executing foreach loop directly, do this:

```
<? if (isset($uerrors)): ?>
    <? foreach ($uerrors as $uerror): ?>
      <span><?= $uerror; ?></span>
    <? endforeach; ?> 
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Besides, I also checked the [dashboard/create-post](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog/blob/master/application/views/dashboard/create-post.php) view and I didn't find any foreach loop so that I can verify. Is it the correct file or another file?

Comment: I did not push that part to GitHub, it throws an error. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize  $data['uerrors'] as null because you are using it on the front end

```
$data['uerrors'] = '';
```

or check the value is not empty on the frontend.

Frontend, you can do this as:

```
<?php  if (isset($uerrors) && $uerrors != '') {
            foreach ($uerrors as $uerror) {
                echo '<span>' . $uerror . '</span>';
            }
        } ?>
```

Your controller will be:

```
 $data = array();
        // Upload image
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        /*You need to initialize  $data['uerrors'] as null because you are using it on front end*/
        $data['uerrors'] = '';
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('FilePath')) {
            $data['uerrors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
            $this->load->view('partials/footer');
        } else {
            if (isset($_POST{'your_file'})) {
                /*'check your images here that you are receiving from front end'*/
            } else {
                /*If there is no image, then default image is*/
                $post_image = 'default.jpg';
            }
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }
```

You can further find useful posts on [How to upload image in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315962/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter)

Comment: This work for me. checking variable that it is not null is the solution.