# How can I store validation errors related to image upload as flash massages in this Codeigniter 3 application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic **blog application** with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

The posts, of course, have main images. There is a *default image* if no image is uploaded by the user.

There are restrictions on image files a user can upload:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '2048';
```

I have managed to display the upload error messages that correspond to the configuration above (for your curiosity and/or use, the code is **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085292/4512005)**).

For the `update()` method however, since there are redirects involved, *all* form validation messages are stored as "flash messages".

```
public function update() {
    // Form data validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    // Update slug (from title)
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $slug = url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title')), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, $id);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }
    } else {
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
    }

// Upload image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['name'] != null) {
        // Use name field in do_upload method
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {

            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            // Dysplay upload validation errors 
            // only if a file is uploaded and there are errors
            if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
                $errors = [];
            }

            if (!empty($errors)) {
                $data['upload_errors'] = $errors;
            }

        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $post_image = $data[ 'raw_name'].$data[ 'file_ext'];
        }
    }
    else {
        $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() && empty($errors)) {
        $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('/' . $slug);
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->run();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
        // this line was added later
        // but the bug persists 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_errors', $errors);
        redirect('/dashboard/posts/edit/' . $slug);
    }
}
```

In the `edit-post.php` **view** I have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="postimage" id="postimage" value="<?php echo $post->post_image; ?>">
<label for="postimage">Upload an image</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="postimage" size="20">
    <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('upload_errors')) { ?>
        <div class="error-messages">
            <?php if(isset($upload_errors)){
                 foreach ($upload_errors as $upload_error) {
                     echo $upload_error;
                 }
            }?>
        </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I have not been able to add the image upload errors messages as "flash messages".

How can I do that?

Comment: I think the problem is in the line `if(isset($upload_errors)..etc..`, at least in the code you provide, I can't see how $upload_errors was sent to the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In edit-post.php you have to change:

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('upload_errors')) { ?>
```

With:

```
<?php if ($upload_errors = $this->session->flashdata('upload_errors')) { ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide a (brief) explanation of why this is necessary? I am not that good eith PHP, I'm learning...

Comment: You try to use `$upload_errors` in the edit-post.php view (`if(isset($upload_errors))`) but this variable is not defined. That's why you need first to asign returned value of `$this->session->flashdata('upload_errors')` to `$upload_errors`.

Comment: So, there is a mistake **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085292/4512005)** too? However, it works with no problems in that case.

Comment: In second case works because you use `$this->load->view('partials/header', $data);` and in `$data` array you already have set `'upload_errors'` key. The `$this->load->view()` method transform the keys of second parameter (`$data` in this case) in variables in the view files, so if you have $data['upload_errors'] set in your controller in the view files you can use $upload_errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
$this->session->set_flashdata('upload_errors', $errors);
```

Or you can create an `$errorArray` from `validation_errors()` and `$errors`.

Comment: It makes sense, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I do the exact same thing (upload errors go into a flashdata element). Here's how it works for me:

(I'll skip the upload config... but for this example, it's stored in an array conveniently named `$config`)

**In my controller:**

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "An error ocurred: ".$this->upload->display_errors());
   $this->session->set_flashdata('alert_class', "alert-danger");
}

else
{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "Upload successful");
   $this->session->set_flashdata('alert_class', "alert-success");

}
```

**In my view (all my views carry this code)**

```
<?php
if (null !== $this->session->flashdata('message'))
{ ?>
    <div class="alert <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('alert_class'); ?> text-center mb-2"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-fw"></i> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?></div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

In this way, if I don't set a flashdata element called `message` the view won't even display the DIV where alert is displayed. If, on the other hand, I do set the `message` element, a col-12 alert is displayed with the message I defined and styled with the alert class I want (success, warning, danger, info, etc)

This will only work for upload validation errors. In your multipart form you may also have regular validation errors which you should check for separately. You can do the same with a flash element:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', validation_errors());
```

I use the same element name (`message`) because I'd stop upon the first error, So there would be no upload error and form validation error in the same display.

Comment: How would you fit your *logic* in the code I have provided?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public function update() 
{
    // Form data validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $form_is_valid = $this->form_validation->run()
    $errors = [];

    // Update slug (from title)
    if ($form_is_valid) {
        $slug = url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title')), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, $id);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }
    } else {
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
        $errors[] = validation_errors();
    }

// Upload image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['name'] != null) {
        // Use name field in do_upload method
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {

            $upload_errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            // Dysplay upload validation errors 
            // only if a file is uploaded and there are errors
            if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
                $upload_errors = [];
            }

            if (!empty($upload_errors)) {
                $data['upload_errors'] = $upload_errors;
                $errors[] = $upload_errors;
            }

        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $post_image = $data[ 'raw_name'].$data[ 'file_ext'];
        }
    }
    else {
        $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('/' . $slug);
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', $errors);
        redirect('/dashboard/posts/edit/' . $slug);
    }
}
```

`$this->form_vlaidation->run()` is called only once.
Errors are saved both (form validation & upload) in the same array.
Post is updated only if `$errors` is empty.

You should think how you can improve the code further.

Comment: It does not.  it throws this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$errors' (T_VARIABLE)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one .Add this in constructor

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('errors');
```

and remove session data after use it in view

```
 $this->session->unset_userdata('errors');
```

Comment: In controller you are using 'errors' as variable name  " $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors())'" 
But in view you are using "upload_errors" $this->session->flashdata('upload_errors')

Comment: And one more point  "$upload_errors" does not work after redirect. you have to use flashdata for displaying errors

Comment: the `errors` variable in `$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors())'` hold the errors (error messages) that are **not** related to the upload process. Si I have added this line: `$this->session->set_flashdata('upload_errors', $errors);` but it does not work.